# if-else is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to display the value returned by the php when a ajax call made to it with specified parameter.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
    $service_id = mt_rand( 10000000, 99999999 );
    $query = "insert into `service` (`id`,`time`,`date`,`city`,`service_type`,`locality`,`name`,`area`,`phone`,`address`)    values('$service_id','$time','$date','$city','$service','$locality','$name','$area','$phone','$address')";
    $result = $sql->query( $query );
    if ( $result ) 
        $x = $service_id;
    else
        $x = 0;

    echo $x;
?>
```

This is my ajax function:

```
var xml = ajax();
if (xml) {
    xml.open("POST", url);
    xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            var reply = xml.responseText;
            var x = reply.length;
            if (x == 8){
                document.getElementById('login-form').style.visibilty='visible';
                document.getElementById('seconday-form').style.visibility='hidden';
            }
            else
               document.getElementById('message').innerHTML=reply;
        }
    }
    xml.send(data);
```

Everything works fine except the last if-else block. `if` condition never gets executed even the returned value from php is of length 8.

**Update** I have included the code which will be executed on each condition true

Comment: Is your actual code indented like that? Even if it is properly indented, skipping braces in `if/else` blocks is a bad idea.

Comment: in addition to what Steve said, unless youve missed it out on your c+p, youve left a `}` out in the javascript at the end of the code block

Comment: The last `if..else` has exactly the same code, so how do you even know which of the two is being called...

Comment: I wouldnt say it is necessarily a bad idea. Its ok in this ocassion as its just a one-liner.. However, i dont understand what's the purpose of that if/else condition. Both if and else block are producing the same thing.

Comment: You should not generate an id like that, just use the database's auto-increment value.

Comment: why are you creating `$x` in that manner? Why not just a simple `1` or `0` (boolean)?

Comment: All the comments are correct, but we should not forget, this is not a code review.. Therefore I don't think this is deserving of a downvote anyway.

Comment: @Bas van stein the  value from php is either going to be a 8 digit no or a 0 then they will trigger some event which are not in this code

Comment: maybe you should output the value of `x` in your ajax code, to avoid stumbling over some non printing character.

Comment: Could it be that OP isn't taking into account javascript asynchronous nature?